# Помогите с настройкой Brackets

Tags: javascript, brackets

Здравствуйте.
Нужно сделать в Brackets, что бы тег перемещался через строчку, а писать можно было сразу между тегами с пробелами или табуляцией.

```
<div>|</div> при нажатии ввод что бы выходило так
<div>
    |
</div>
```

В Sublime Text 3 именно так, как сделать в Brackets?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это не программирование.

Comment: @Aid, вопросы про настройку окружения относятся к тематике ru.so, хотя на en.so это был бы оффтоп, но у нас нет аналога superuser

Answer (score 0):

Установка плагина emmet решает эту проблему.